# How do I use PDFBox with Asp.Net for parsing pdf files with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I recently downloaded PDFBox, and I am trying to figure out how to parse pdf files with it in Asp.Net to no avail, in fact, I don't even know where to start. Has anyone been able to do this in asp.net (C# preferrably)?

Is there any other ways to parse text out of a PDF in Asp.Net?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this out:
http://naspinski.net/post/ParsingReading-a-PDF-file-with-C-and-AspNet-to-text.aspx