# Using EPiServer to publish a PDF document

Tags: pdf, publishing, episerver

We have an EPI Server site. We would like to publish the contents from a PDF document as part of a published page.

The published page should have the right menu and the top menu of the site, but the contents should come from the PDF document.

Is there a PDF viewer or another way to do this?

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPiServer can't do it out of the box but [Migradoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) is a good free library for .NET

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built into EPiServer but you can use any Dotnet third-party PDF-product that does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have one that you would recommend?

Comment: Have never needed to use one yet.

Here's another similiar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629327/how-do-i-use-pdfbox-with-asp-net-for-parsing-pdf-files-with-c

Looking around a bit there's a open source project that might work you as well:
http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/